# Отправка стикеров в telegram bot python | telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Я хочу реализовать отправку файлов webp в телеграмм бота.
Вот мой код:

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot("6102586847:AAENFQ7zf7Kj4w9Pho5CpkrvDbzYEASjDnU")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, url)

bot.polling()
```

Если url = 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.webp', то код выполняется успешно.

Но если 'https://ve.lordfilm.film/uploads/mini/lord5/99/1673290010-615733236.webp', то возникает ошибка:

```
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified
```

Подскажите в чём может быть проблема. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telegram API ругается на имя .webp-файла. Вместо того, чтобы отправлять стикеры с помощью ссылок, вы можете отправлять их с помощью данных самого изображения:

```
import requests

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    webp_data = requests.get(url).content
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, webp_data)
```